# How to store structure as (void *) and retrieve same

Tags: c++, casting, void-pointers

I am learning to use void pointers. Here I have created a resource class which can store any type of structure in `(void *)` and now when I try to get that structure back in `(void *)`, I am not able to get same data back. Please help here

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class resource{
private:
    void* data;
public:
    void set(void* val){
        data = val;
    }
    void get(void* val){
        val = data;
    }
    
};

class student{
    struct st{
        int id;
        int age;
    };
public: 
    void func(){
        st *st1 = (st *)malloc(sizeof(st));
        st1->id = 5;
        st1->age = 10;

        resource *rsrc = new resource();
        rsrc->set((void*)st1);
            
        void *data;
        rsrc->get(&data);
        st *st2 = (st*)data;
        cout<<"get data %d"<<st2->id<<endl;     // HERE I want to get same data back
    }
};

int main() {
    student *stu = new student();
    stu->func();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void get(void** val){*val = data;}` or just return data instead of using an out param.

Comment: parameters are passed by value, pointers are no exception.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I'm pretty sure its valid (although definitely not idiomatic modern c++) to use malloc for PODs in c++.

Comment: @MikeVine oh right, i was too paranoic. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the signature of `get` to return a `void *`:

```
void *get(){
    return data;
}
```

And subsequently:

```
void *data = rsrc->get();
```

Also, it is idiomatic to use `new`, rather than `malloc`, to construct objects, although for POD (plain-old-data) types, either is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Your get method won't return any value. You are passing a void pointer to it and inside the method, you overwrite that void pointer. However, that only overwrites the local copy of the void pointer and does not return a value. As others stated, you either have to pass a pointer to a pointer or use the return statement to return the value of the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, @PaulSanders made the correct suggestion. You should use the getter/setter pattern. Also, he is correct that you should use `new` and `delete` in idomatic C++.

For user-created classes, most people specify classes with the first letter as a captial:

```
class Resource {};
class Student {};
```

It depends on your coding standard. It matters less whether you use [camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) or not so long as you use a consistent [naming convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)).

Also, we generally try to prevent loss of type information in C++. Of course, you can use a C-style cast which will just reinterpret the pointer as the specified type but that is considered bad style and likely to cause problems.